# Can't set a map with EPSG4326

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am using Leaflet to draw a mapbox map, but I need it to be in EPSG4326 coordinate system.

If I run this code:

```
     var mymap = L.map('map', {
      center: {lon: 12.39258, lat: 41.69906},
      zoom: 5,
      maxZoom: 8,
      crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
      zoomControl: true
    });

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox.streets-satellite',
    accessToken: '<mytoken>'
    }).addTo(mymap);
```

the Tiles doesn't load, with a 404 NOT FOUND error. If I comment out the line:

```
crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
```

the map loads fine, but it is not in EPSG4326 coordinate system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably the Mapbox tiles you use are available only in Web Mercator (EPSG3857), not in Equirectangular (EPSG4326).

Leaflet does not transform the tiles from the tile source according to the CRS, but the position of relative features (markers, lines, etc.)

The tile source must already be in the appropriate projection.

Comment: That's weird, as I am reading this from Mapbox site: "Mapbox supports the popular Web Mercator projection, and currently does not support any other projections for display. "

Comment: Hi, please can you kindly clarify what is weird? Your quote sounds pretty clear to me that it confirms the above: only Web Mercator tiles are available, not Equirectangular.

Comment: Yes, right. I messed up! So, no way to represent a 4326 layer over a mapbox?

Comment: No way to easily transform the Mapbox tiles into an Equirectangular projection indeed. That being said, if your objective is to overlay another layer, you might have more options with that layer. If you need help on that, feel free to open a new question with details on your other layer and what you are trying to achieve.